# OpenLDAP v2.4 enable logging

Tags: logs, syslog, openldap

I have openldap v 2.4 running on centos7 and working but i cannot get it to log anything.
I have tried adding the below line to the rsyslog.conf file but i still do not get any log file.

```
LOCAL4.*        /var/log/openldap/slapd.log
```

When i added this line i ran the below command to reload the rsyslog conf and also stopped and started openldap.

```
pkill -HUP rsyslog
```

I cant find any more instruction on how to enable logging.

Comment: This might be a typo-based Q/A; what happens if you point LOCAL4.* to `/var/log/openldap/somefilename.log` instead?

Comment: I had tried that as well but nothing in my log file.

Comment: (you'd have to HUP syslog again...?)

Comment: Did that do it?

Comment: Unfortunately no change

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To enable OpenLDAP debugs, you would want to add the following to your `slapd.conf`

```
loglevel <level> (eg: stats)
```

If you do not use `slapd.conf`, you may then pass that option to the slapd service. In debian/ubuntu, you would find some `/etc/default/slapd` file, you may update its `SLAPD_OPTIONS`:

```
$ grep SLAPD_OPTIONS /etc/default/slapd
SLAPD_OPTIONS="-s 256"
```

We may then restart slapd:

```
systemctl restart slapd
```

Valid slapd log levels would include:

```
| -1          | Enable all debugging                          |
|  0          | Enable no debugging                           |
|  1          | Trace function calls                          |
|  2          | Debug packet handling                         |
|  4          | Heavy trace debugging                         |
|  8          | Connection management                         |
|  16         | Log packets sent and recieved                 |
|  32         | Search filter processing                      |
|  64         | Configuration file processing                 |
|  128        | Access control list processing                |
|  256        | Stats log connections, operations and results |
|  512        | Stats log entries sent                        |
|  1024       | Log communication with shell backends         |
|  2048       | Log entry parsing debugging                   |
```

For further details, see http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/slapdconfig.html

---

Besides, as Jeff pointed it out, your syslog configuration looks wrong to begin with.

```
LOCAL4.*        /var/log/openldap/
```

Should probably be:

```
LOCAL4.*        /var/log/openldap/some-file.log
```

Or:

```
LOCAL4.*        /var/log/openldap.log
```

Comment: Does that send to syslog, or write natively? (Just curious if I'm on the right track with my comments at all)

Comment: Sends to syslog. By default, you won't see much regarding binds, searches, ..., or at all, unless you pass slapd with some option.

Comment: Good to know; thank you! Would you consider adding a syslog.conf correction away from the OP's `/var/log/openldap/` target?

Comment: Im not using slapd.conf. i was under the impression it had been replaced with the cn=config.ldif file? i tried adding the loglevel to this file but still no logs.
I did find a file /etc/sysconfig/slapd  and had a SLAPD_OPTIONS line commented out but when i add -d 256 and uncommented it ldap would not start.

Comment: @SYN anything extra you can suggest would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Right, my mistake: the `-d` in sysconfig, in addition to setting log level, also prefents slapd from forking. We should actually use `-s`, to only tune loglevel while still starting a background service. And yes, slapd.conf is slowly going away, which is when you'ld set that loglevel from sysconfigs / defaults.

Comment: @SYN thanks for coming back. I swapped the -d for a -s in sysconfig/slapd file and slapd now starts but i still am not getting anothing in my nominated log file. I am at a loss what i am missing.

Comment: Could you share your rsyslog configuration?

Comment: The line i have added is LOCAL4.*        /var/log/openldap/slapd.log
Let me know if you need more of the file.

Comment: I'm looking for something that could discard those logs before your addition. In doubt, we could also check for SElinux (in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`, look for denied messages). Does the `/var/log/openldap` directory exists already? Otherwise make sure it does.

Comment: i couldnt see anything wrong in the files mentioned but it is now logging after i stopped and started rsyslog. Thanks for your help

Comment: Oh well, perfect then! Thanks for confirming.